# Install from unknown sources on Nook Tablet

Tags: unknown-sources, nook-tablet

I am using a rooted NOOK Tablet with Android Gingerbread, and am installing an application from an email. I am using the NT Hidden Settings application to enable the installation of apps from unknown sources. I check the box and click OK knowing the dangers of 3rd party applications. I go back to the email, click the attachment, and when I hit the installation screen, after I had just checked it, it says install blocked. I returned to the setting and the check box I had filled in was now empty again, and I am caught in the loop forever. What can I do to make the app install?

Comment: Is your tablet rooted?

Comment: Usually that shouldn't need a separate app to enable `unknown-sources`. Have you checked in *Settings->Applications* for the corresponding checkbox? Sometimes it also hides in the *Settings->Development* section. Maybe it's just the fault of your "NT Hidden Settings", e.g. that it doesn't *save* your changes.

Comment: @Izzy The Nook tablet doesn't expose that setting out of the box.

Comment: Oh -- another "closed environment" (or "apple-ish Android"). Well, that leaves at least the possibility to use `adb install some.apk`, which doesn't require that setting to be enabled (see [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) for how to get ADB working)

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my above comment, one way would be:

1. Get ADB working on your computer (see: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575))
2. Download the `.apk` file to your computer
3. Switch on *USB Debugging* on your device, and then connect it to your computer via USB (order is important here: first enable the option, then connect)
4. Use `adb install <file_name.apk>` to install the app

For subsequent installs, you of course can ommit the first step, as ADB should already be set up then :)

Alternative approach (untested):

1. Install some terminal app on your device (e.g. [Android Terminal Emulator](http://www.appbrain.com/app/android-terminal-emulator/jackpal.androidterm))
2. Save the `.apk` to your SDCard
3. Start the terminal app, and run `pm install </path/to/filename.apk>`

Again, the first step is only needed once. I've not tested that second method, so I'm not sure whether it requires root or the "unknown sources" option. As `adb install` only seems to be a wrapper to `pm install`, the latter is not that likely.